# Quantum Schubert cell algebra and quantum odd-dimensional euclidean space

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, quantum-groups

De Concini, Kac, Procesi introduced quantum Schubert cell algebra associated to a complex Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ which is denoted by $\mathcal{U}^{w}_{\epsilon}$ where $w$ is an element of Weyl group of $\mathfrak{g}$ and constructed in https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/93081.

In https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.3486 , Section 2.5, page 14 Goodearl and Launois introduced the quantum odd-dimensional euclidean space.

I was wondering whether the odd dimensional quantum euclidean space is a special case of quantum Schubert cell algebras or not. If yes, can anyone help me to understand why?